# Removing the Character before Dash

Tags: oracle

I am to extract characters from a string before and after the dash (-). So far, I was able to use this code below to return all the numbers before dash:

```
SELECT 
INSTR('100-7', '-'),
SUBSTR('100-7', 1, INSTR('100-7', '-')-1)
FROM dual;
```

Now I am trying to find a way to return all the characters after dash. So if I have a string:

```
20-150
```

THe query should only return me 150. Is there anyway I can do this? By the way, I am using Oracle. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will return everything after the dash

```
SELECT SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '-')+1) invalue
  FROM (SELECT '20-150' value FROM dual) t;
```

Output:

```
| INVALUE |
-----------
|     150 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8331)

And putting both together

```
SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '-') - 1) lvalue, 
       SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '-') + 1) rvalue
  FROM (SELECT '20-150' value FROM dual) t;
```

Output:

```
| LVALUE | RVALUE |
-------------------
|     20 |    150 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8334)

Comment: Hi Peter, I owe you one beer. Thanks for helping out. Your code works great.

Answer (score 1):

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE` :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('20-150','(.*)-','') 
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

using REGEXP_SUBSTR :

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('20-15055555555', '[^-]+', 1, 2) rep
  FROM DUAL;
```

you can try this

Answer (score -1):

The query should be something like this.

```
select substr('P_A_VA1234_1_EE',(INSTR('P_A_VA1234_1_EE','_',1,2)+1),(INSTR('P_A_VA1234_1_EE','_',1,4)-(INSTR('P_A_VA1234_1_EE','_',1,2)+1)))original from dual

select substr(shipment_gid,(INSTR(shipment_gid,'_',1,2)+1),(INSTR(shipment_gid,'_',1,4)-(INSTR(shipment_gid,'_',1,2)+1)))original from dual

SUBSTR(S.SHIPMENT_GID,8,8) LOADID,

select substr(shipment_gid,(INSTR(shipment_gid,'_',1,2)+1),(INSTR(shipment_gid,'_',1,4)-(INSTR(shipment_gid,'_',1,2)+1)))load,shipment_gid from shipment where shipment_gid like '%DHL/CLS.CLS_CV_%';

SUBSTR(S.SHIPMENT_GID,(INSTR(S.SHIPMENT_GID,'_',1,2)+1),(INSTR(S.SHIPMENT_GID,'_',1,4)-(INSTR(S.SHIPMENT_GID,'_',1,2)+1)))
```