# Sequence of Numbers in a Varchar Column

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following sample table and data:

```
create table test_assignment_number
(
    assignment_id       number,
    assignment_number   varchar2(250),
    change_detail       varchar2(250)
);

insert into test_assignment_number (assignment_id, assignment_number, change_detail) values (1, '3807734', 'Initial Value');
insert into test_assignment_number (assignment_id, assignment_number, change_detail) values (2, '3807734', 'Some Minor Changes');
insert into test_assignment_number (assignment_id, assignment_number, change_detail) values (3, '3807734', 'More Minor Changes');
insert into test_assignment_number (assignment_id, assignment_number, change_detail) values (4, '3807734', 'Last Minor Change');
insert into test_assignment_number (assignment_id, assignment_number, change_detail) values (5, '3807734-2', 'Major Change');
insert into test_assignment_number (assignment_id, assignment_number, change_detail) values (6, '3807734-2', 'Minor Change to the Major Change');

select  *
from    test_assignment_number;

assignment_id   assignment_number   change_detail
-------------   -----------------   ----------------------------------
1               3807734             Initial Value
2               3807734             Some Minor Changes
3               3807734             More Minor Changes
4               3807734             Last Minor Change
5               3807734-2           Major Change
6               3807734-2           Minor Change to the Major Change
```

The Assignment_Number Column was inputted manually from the application by putting in a "-2" or a "-3" for major changes.
I would want to generate this programatically by using a function. With the help of some SO posts [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084644/oracle-12c-select-string-after-last-occurrence-of-a-character), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195995/removing-the-character-before-dash)), Here's what i got so far:

```
select  assignment_number||'-'||sequence_num new_assignment_number
from   (select  max(regexp_substr(assignment_number, '[^-]+',1,1)) assignment_number -- gets the base Assignment_Number
            ,   max(regexp_substr(assignment_number, '[^-]+$'))+1  sequence_num      -- gets the next sequence 
        from    test_assignment_number
        where   regexp_substr(assignment_number, '[^-]+$') <> assignment_number);
```

Result:

```
NEW_ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER
---------------------
3807734-3
```

However, I was wondering if there is a better or simpler way to do this.
What instances/occurrences may cause this SQL code to behave differently and give an undesired output?

Some Footnotes to consider:
I cannot use a sequence because some other employees have other assignment numbers (ex. 9999999-10).
I cannot add another separate column for the Sequence Number as the actual Tables are Oracle Priopietary (Oracle EBS).

Comment: Regardless of approach (the better one proposed by BobC, which unfortunately is not available to you, or the one you are looking for, to work within the constraints you have) - so, regardless of approach, you need to clarify two things, and the requirement must be 100% deterministic. First: How do you recognize major changes? You can't simply look for the word "Major" or even "Major Change" in the `change_detail` column, since that phrase also appears in the details of a minor change. So, how do you recognize major changes? Does the detail **begin** with "Major Change"?  (continued below)

Comment: Does the detail **equal** "Major Change" (and nothing else in the string?) Also, how about capitalization - are the words always INITCAP (initial letter capitalized), or should the comparisons be insensitive to case? (You always have problems like this when you have "lookup" information such as "MINOR CHANGE" and "MAJOR CHANGE" markers stored in a free-text field instead of a small dimension table). Then, the second question is how do you know which major change gets `-2` and which gets `-3`, etc.? Is it by `assignment_id` ascending?

Comment: To clarify my FIRST question: Can you have something like "Second Major Change" in the `details` column? That would be really bad; how do you recognize this is a major change, and not something else?

Comment: @mathguy, the major changes are manually determined by the End-Users. Originally, the process is the End-Users go into the Application, do the changes then create the -2 or -3 assignment. I'm developing a mass uploader of those changes and assign a new assignment number "-X".

Answer (score 0):

I would have a new column called assignment_version (or something appropriate). That way assignment_number would stay assignment number; it's meaning would not change. Furthermore, you would not need to do substringing or regexing and other such shenanigans, to get just the assignment_number for example . Your new column would contain the 2 or 3 as per you example. If your assignment_version had to be sequential, it's easy to get the latest one in use via something like:

```
select max(assignment_version) 
from test_assignment_number
where assingnment_number = '3807734'
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i agree, but sadly the actual tables are fixed and i am restricted with the said logic and structure for the meantime. thoughts?

Comment: It's such a bad idea, I highly recommend you try and change the table design. You are likely to run into more problems in the future; including performance !  I'm sure the "table's can't change" is a knee jerk reaction from someone. But if I were you, I would mock up both designs, with a representative data volume, do some performance test and let data drive your decision.

Comment: i edited the question to specify i cannot change the table structure. the actual table is an Oracle EBS Application Table. Data is usually entered from the application and the business rule has always been to add a dash ("-2") for new assignments.

Comment: And EBS allows you to do that? Oh well... :(

Comment: yes, because the "Assignment Number" field in the EBS application is a `VARCHAR2` Column. In my former company, I was assigned an Assignment number that was 113F0001 before, and now, its 3807734.

Comment: I meant logically. Does EBS now not consider 3807734 and 3807734-2 as two different assignments, when they are essentially the same? I just think you're setting yourself up for problems. But then what do I know...