# Removing all characters before a given special character [Oracle SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle

my oracle table has a column with these data:

| ROW_ID | FILE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ZASWEFFT%Contract V1.pdf |
| 2 | ZZZZxxxx12%Contract 03.12.14.pdf |

I need to remove everything before and including the % character, which would give me:

| ROW_ID | FILE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Contract V1.pdf |
| 2 | Contract 03.12.14.pdf |

I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195995/removing-the-character-before-dash)
I changed it to fit my need and the select statement works:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '%')+1) invalue
  FROM (SELECT FILE_NAME value FROM SFDC.PROJECT_ATT));
```

result:

| INVALUE |
| --- |
| Contract V1.pdf |
| Contract 03.12.14.pdf |

But I'm not able to transform this into an **update** statement. My last try was:

```
UPDATE SIEBEL.S_PROJ_ATT T1
   SET T1.FILE_NAME =
       (SELECT SUBSTR(value,
                      INSTR(value,
                            '%') + 1) invalue
          FROM (SELECT T2.FILE_NAME value
                  FROM SIEBEL.S_PROJ_ATT T2
                 WHERE T1.ROW_ID = T2.ROW_ID))
```

Oracle says the syntax is rubbish: ORA-00904: "T1"."ID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made it too complicted

> ```
> CREATE TABLE S_PROJ_ATT  (
>   ROW_ID INTEGER,
>   FILE_NAME VARCHAR(32)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO S_PROJ_ATT 
>   (ROW_ID, FILE_NAME)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'ZASWEFFT%Contract V1.pdf');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO S_PROJ_ATT 
>   (ROW_ID, FILE_NAME)
> VALUES  
>   ('2', 'ZZZZxxxx12%Contract 03.12.14.pdf');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE S_PROJ_ATT  
> SET FILE_NAME = SUBSTR(FILE_NAME, INSTR(FILE_NAME, '%')+1)
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM S_PROJ_ATT
> ```
>
> ```
> ROW_ID | FILE_NAME            
> -----: | :--------------------
>      1 | Contract V1.pdf      
>      2 | Contract 03.12.14.pdf
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1aaea973ec5181ac24f854972c6e93f0)*

Comment: Thanks, much simpler indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subqueries; you can just do:

```
update s_proj_att
set file_name = substr(file_name, instr(file_name, '%') + 1)
where instr(file_name, '%') > 0;
```

The `where` clause stops it trying to update any file names without the `*%` at the start.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f54033b075e353a8f188378bc9b5ed34)

The question you linked to is using a subquery - or line view - to generate the value from a string literal. You don't need to do that here, as you already have the column value.